# Typesafe Config: How to Create Conditional Configurations

Tags: typesafe-config

Does Typesafe Config allow to create conditional configurations?

I need to set a key depending on the value of another key:

```
ssl = true

#if ssl == true
host = "https://localhost"
#else
host = "http://localhost"
#end if
```

Of course the code above does't work... I just wanted to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly, no. For the particular example you gave, you could use optional properties:

```
protocol = "http"
protocol = ${?MY_PROTOCOL}

host = ${protocol}://localhost
```

Then if your application was started with either -Dprotocol=https as an argument to java, or with MY_PROTOCOL=https as an environment variable, you'd get https in the host.